# Custom v-on:click.prevent functionality

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've no idea what to call this so I don't know what to search for. I've looked around the directives but not sure this is what it is either, basically, I want to be able to do:

```
v-on:click.validate="runCode"
```

Where `validate` is a custom method that runs before `runCode` is called (much in the same way `.prevent` works.

Can someone point me to some docs / an example?

More Context: I've written some custom form components that feed validation data into my state. These form components can be used as and when i.e

```
<msp-input
          v-model="form.username"
          :validation="{ required, email }"
          float-label="Email Address"
          type="email"
        />
```

I want to be able to write a button on any of the forms that causes the validation popup to show if the state shows some validation has failed. I could have an `<msp-button>` component to do it but thought it would be nice to have an inline `.validate`.

Comment: They're called modifiers and there's no way to add your own custom modifier to an existing directive that I am aware of. You could write your own version of `v-on` though and handle whatever modifiers you wanted to.

Comment: @Bert Ah, I see. Well, thanks for letting me know what they're called. I think I'll go with my other option of writing my own button component and passing a callback through in that case. Feel free to add an answer as it gave me the information I needed.

Comment: For info: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6982 This is what I wanted but Evan You said no :) 
He has a good point though, write a wrapper. I could just add the wrapper to a global mixin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example `v-on:click.validate`, `validate` is called a modifier, and `click` is an argument to the `v-on` directive. This is covered in the documentation for [custom directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).

There is no way currently to add your own custom modifiers to built in directives (this is covered in several issues on the github repo). You could potentially write your own directive and handle arguments and modifiers as you see fit.

Otherwise your other approach sounds fine.

Comment: I've gone for `v-on:click="doValidation(runCode)"` with `doValidation` located in a global mixin I already use for validation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why not just do v-on:click="validate" then put runCode at the last line of your validate method.